# Run unit tests with spring boot, "no runnable methods" error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, kotlin

I'm running unit tests with Spring boot, but I get a weird `no runnable` error. The tests pass by the way, but after all test have ended successfully, I get this weird error out of nowhere:

```
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:137)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner.<init>(SpringRunner.java:49)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

How do I fix this? Why is Spring boot looking for a runnable in my tests?

Here is an example of my code

```
package ca.bell.uc.hello.world

import org.junit.Assert
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner


@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
internal class example {

    @Test
    fun f() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true)
    }
}
```

And here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Thanks

P.S. This is Kotlin

Comment: are your tests annotated with `@Test` ? - please display some of your code (a minimal set) to know more and help troubleshooting

Comment: @blurfus Added a code sample. Yes, they are annotated

Comment: We're using Kotlin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to use JUnit 5 `@Test` annotation because of import:

`import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`

In the console log we can see that JUnit 4 is used.

If you want to work with JUnit 4 you should use the import:

`import org.junit.Test`

Comment: good catch! using junit 4 runner with junit 5 `@Test` annotations... that might be it

Comment: In my case I just removed @Runwith which is from Junit4 and simply used @ SpringbootTest, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it's the mix of **JUnit4** and **JUnit5**. I had the same thing with tests with `@Ignore` or `@Disabled` that would not want to get ignored based on which `@Test` it was.

You can avoid this issue with spring by updating your spring dependencies and remove the **Junit4** dependencies from your `build.gradle.kts` so that you won't mix them (tested with Gradle v6, check the [groovy syntax](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleDependency.html#exclude-java.util.Map-) if you use `build.gradle`).

```kotlin
  testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
    exclude(module = "junit")
    exclude(module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    exclude(module = "mockito-core")
  }
  testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.2")
  testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api")
  testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
```

Once you have that you don't need to use `@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)` you can see the difference in your import, they should all contains *"jupiter"* and your class could look like this:

```kotlin
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

internal class ExampleTest {

  @Test
  fun test() {
    Assertions.assertTrue(true)
  }
}
```

Comment: The `exclude(module = ...` syntax will give an error. (Though even after fixing that, this solution didn't work for me.) The correct syntax is shown in the docs: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleDependency.html#exclude-java.util.Map-

Comment: Oh yeah, that's the syntax in your `build.gradle.kts`, I'll add the link for the groovy syntax. Also you may be using other dependencies that have a mix of both. Try `gradle dependencies` to see which one so you can exclude them, or use the exclude all syntax.